# Regex word replacement in a dataset showing no change in the result

Tags: python, string, numpy, dataset, regexp-replace

I have a dataset array with this structure

```
print(type(test_small_testval))
print((test_small_testval.features))

<class 'datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset'>
{'premise': Value(dtype='string', id=None), 'hypothesis': Value(dtype='string', id=None), 'label': ClassLabel(num_classes=3, names=['entailment', 'neutral', 'contradiction'], names_file=None, id=None)}
```

I can access the hypothesis column of the dataset by doing this

```
for i in range(len(test_small_testval)):
    print(test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i])
```

As an example, the first two elements can be viewed as :

```
print(test_small_testval['hypothesis'][0:2])
['The owner threw the toy', 'The dog walked across the fallen log.']
```

In this column 'hypothesis' I want to go over each string and replace like this:

```
test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i] = re.sub(r'\bshe\b', r'them', test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i])
            test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i] = re.sub(r'\bhe\b', r'them', test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i])
            test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i] = re.sub(r'\bher\b', r'them', test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i])
            test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i] = re.sub(r'\bhim\b', r'them', test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i])
            test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i] = re.sub(r'\bdog\b', r'animal', test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i])
            test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i] = re.sub(r'\bcat\b', r'animal', test_small_testval['hypothesis'][i])
```

It does not seem to be replacing the words in that specific column. I thought I was overwriting the string with the original string but the approach seems fine to me.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I converted everything to pandas dataframe and the same approach worked well